# Line ending problem while publishing google sheet as a csv file

Tags: csv, google-sheets, newline, export-to-csv

I uses "File" → "Publish to the web" to get the URL that I can download the exported csv file. But when I check the csv file, I found that the line ending of this file is crlf. Can I set the line ending to lf? I can't find where to set this while I uses the Publish function.

I found someone answer on the google docs help forum which shows the line ending should be lf, but it seems not anymore now. link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/WKlDzsNJeoQ/mg9AXJsmqJcJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux and Mac OS an option is to use the `dos2unix` command line tool to convert the newlines from CRLF to LF. Some examples:

```
$ # In-place conversion.
$ dos2unix file.csv

$ # Conversion writing to a new file. The existing file is not modified.
$ dos2unix -n file_dos.csv file_unix.csv
```

Depending on the system it may be necessary to use a package manager to download the `dos2unix` tool.